# Getting next element while cycling through a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3]

running = True
while running:
    for elem in li:
        thiselem = elem
        nextelem = li[li.index(elem)+1]
```

When this reaches the last element, an `IndexError` is raised (as is the case for any list, tuple, dictionary, or string that is iterated). I actually want at that point for `nextelem` to equal `li[0]`. My rather cumbersome solution to this was

```
while running:
    for elem in li:
        thiselem = elem
        nextelem = li[li.index(elem)-len(li)+1]   # negative index
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Consider leaving out the while loop. It seems irrelevant to the question. If it is relevant, consider explaining why.

Comment: I want to cycle through a list indefinitely, hence the while/for loop combination. Sorry, didn't explain that.

Comment: I assume you would also, ideally, like to be able to stop in the middle of the cycle instead of just at the end?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure I could use `break` for that.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

After thinking this through carefully, I think this is the best way.  It lets you step off in the middle easily without using `break`, which I think is important, and it requires minimal computation, so I think it's the fastest.  It also doesn't require that `li` be a list or tuple.  It could be any iterator.

```
from itertools import cycle

li = [0, 1, 2, 3]

running = True
licycle = cycle(li)
# Prime the pump
nextelem = next(licycle)
while running:
    thiselem, nextelem = nextelem, next(licycle)
```

---

I'm leaving the other solutions here for posterity.

All of that fancy iterator stuff has its place, but not here.  Use the % operator.

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3]

running = True
while running:
    for idx, elem in enumerate(li):
        thiselem = elem
        nextelem = li[(idx + 1) % len(li)]
```

Now, if you intend to infinitely cycle through a list, then just do this:

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3]

running = True
idx = 0
while running:
    thiselem = li[idx]
    idx = (idx + 1) % len(li)
    nextelem = li[idx]
```

I think that's easier to understand than the other solution involving `tee`, and probably faster too.  If you're sure the list won't change size, you can squirrel away a copy of `len(li)` and use that.

This also lets you easily step off the ferris wheel in the middle instead of having to wait for the bucket to come down to the bottom again.  The other solutions (including yours) require you check `running` in the middle of the `for` loop and then `break`.

Comment: +1 Yeah, this is also simple and effective. There's no need for these unnecessarily complex functional solutions to problems which have extremely simple procedural solutions. Python is not a functional language!

Comment: @Mark Byers, thanks!  I do think there's room for a fairly functional solution if the list is fairly small, and I added that.  The whole bit with `running` is not functional, and trying to shoehorn it into a functional solution is ugly.

Comment: @Mark Byers: There, the answer I think is best uses itertools, but in a very minimalistic kind of way.  I think its very fast, and easy to understand.

Comment: I'm such a perfectionist.  It's irritating that after 8 edits it becomes a community wiki answer.  *sigh*

Comment: Aw, that sucks. But thanks for the effort! I think your three solutions are my favourite.

Comment: In Python 3, use `next(licycle)` instead of `licycle.next()`

Comment: love this! `(idx + 1) % len(li)`

Comment: No reset of "running" to `False`?

Comment: @Acebone - I didn't include it because the OP only specified that they wanted that sort of flag and didn't give any logic for when it would be set. Clearly setting that flag to false in the middle of the loop somewhere will result in the loop exiting.

Comment: Reviving this old post because I just used the example code as reference for something, but I have a question. Would you mind explaining the use of "%" in the example above. I don't quite understand it lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

```
while running:
    for elem,next_elem in zip(li, li[1:]+[li[0]]):
        ...
```

Comment: This is my second favorite, after mine.  :-)  Simple is best, but if the list is at all large, this creates two copies of it.

Comment: One of the most pythonic thing I have seen.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a pairwise cyclic iterator:

```
from itertools import izip, cycle, tee

def pairwise(seq):
    a, b = tee(seq)
    next(b)
    return izip(a, b)

for elem, next_elem in pairwise(cycle(li)):
    ...
```

Comment: This is good. It incorporates the while loop and the for loop into one concise loop, which continuously iterates over adjacent pairs in the list, and wraps around at the end.

Comment: +1 for using pairwise - an unofficial library function which exists only in the documentation for itertools. So while you can't import it, it's known to work.

Comment: I think obscuring the test for running inside the for loop and requiring the use of `break` isn't such a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

```
while running:
    lenli = len(li)
    for i, elem in enumerate(li):
        thiselem = elem
        nextelem = li[(i+1)%lenli]
```

Comment: For some reason, this is printing the first element of the list again with the last element.

Answer (score 6):

A rather different way to solve this:

```
   li = [0,1,2,3]

   for i in range(len(li)):

       if i < len(li)-1:

           # until end is reached
           print 'this', li[i]
           print 'next', li[i+1]

       else:

           # end
           print 'this', li[i]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the zip method in Python. This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables

```
    while running:
        for thiselem,nextelem in zip(li, li[1 : ] + li[ : 1]):
            #Do whatever you want with thiselem and nextelem
```

Comment: That's kinda brilliant!

Comment: Note that this is creating a new list; might be something you don't want to do when dealing with huge lists.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3]
while 1:
   for i, item in enumerate(x):
      k = i + 1 if i != len(x) - 1 else 0
      print('Current index {} : {}'.format(i,li[k]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to remove IndexError by incorporating the condition:

```
if(index<(len(li)-1))
```

The error 'index out of range' will not occur now as the last index will not be reached. The idea is to access the next element while iterating. On reaching the penultimate element, you can access the last element.

Use enumerate method to add index or counter to an iterable(list, tuple, etc.). Now using the index+1, we can access the next element while iterating through the list.

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3]

running = True
while running:
    for index, elem in enumerate(li):
        if(index<(len(li)-1)):
            thiselem = elem
            nextelem = li[index+1]
```

Comment: This is a great and succinct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
        li = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        for elem in li:
            if (li.index(elem))+1 != len(li):
                thiselem = elem
                nextelem = li[li.index(elem)+1]
                print 'thiselem',thiselem
                print 'nextel',nextelem
            else:
                print 'thiselem',li[li.index(elem)]
                print 'nextel',li[li.index(elem)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   while running:
        lenli = len(li)
        for i, elem in enumerate(li):
            thiselem = elem
            nextelem = li[(i+1)%lenli] # This line is vital
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please give explanations and not only code for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I've used **enumeration** to handle this problem.

```
storage = ''
for num, value in enumerate(result, start=0):
    content = value
    if 'A' == content:
        storage = result[num + 1]
```

I've used **num** as **Index** here, when it finds the correct value it adds up one to the current index of actual list. Which allows me to maneuver to the next index.

I hope this helps your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For strings list from 1(or whatever > 0) until end.

```
itens = ['car', 'house', 'moon', 'sun']

v = 0
for item in itens:
    b = itens[1 + v]
    print(b)
    print('any other command')
    if b == itens[-1]:
        print('End')
        break
    v += 1
```