# How to iterate over the next element in the map in the inner loop, while coming from the next element of the map in the outer loop?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iterator, logic

I want to replace the new link by the old one, which can be random, but both link should not be the same.

The logic I have written is iterating over the inner loop again, which can cause the link to be set as the same as previous one.

In the function I am passing the value in dictionary format-

```
${oldLinks}=   Set Variable    {"Facebook":"https://www.facebook.com/","Stack Overflow":"http://stackoverflow.com/"}
${newLinks}=   Set Variable    {"Discovery":"http://www.discovery.com/","HowStuffWorks":"http://www.howstuffworks.com/"}
```

This is the function I have written in python + Robot framework -

```
def edit_favorites(d,oldLinks,newLinks):
    oldLinks=json.loads(oldLinks)
    newLinks=json.loads(newLinks)
    BookmarkLinks=oldLinks
    NewBookarks=newLinks
    d.press.back()
    d(hamBergBtn).click()
    d(favorites).click()
    for key,val in BookmarkLinks.iteritems():
        logger.info("Editing the favorites",html=False,also_console=True)
        logger.info("key url"+key,also_console=True)
        # if(d({'textContains':key}))==None:
        #     d({'scrollable':True}).scroll.toEnd()
        for key1,val1 in NewBookarks.iteritems():
            d({'textContains':key}).long_click()
            if d({'textContains':"Copy link URL"}).exists & d({'textContains':"Edit"}).exists & d({'textContains':"Remove"}).exists & d({'textContains':"Cancel"}).exists:
                logger.info("coming here, to edit",also_console=True)
                d({'text':'Edit'}).click()
                d({'resourceId':'com.ex.browser:id/title'}).click()
                if d({"focused":"true"}):
                    d({'resourceId':'com.ex.browser:id/title'}).set_text(key1)
                d({'resourceId':'com.ex.browser:id/address'}).click()
                if d({"focused":"true"}):
                    d({'resourceId':'com.ex.browser:id/address'}).set_text(val1)
                d({'text':'Save'}).click()
                break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError,"Pop up doesn't contain the required fields"
```

Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

```
def edit_favorites(d,oldLinks,newLinks):
oldLinks=json.loads(oldLinks)
newLinks=json.loads(newLinks)
OldBookmarkLabel=oldLinks.keys()
OldBookmarkURL=oldLinks.values()
NewBookarksLabel=newLinks.keys()
NewBookarksURL=newLinks.values()
# d.press.back()
for i in range(len(OldBookmarkLabel)):
    logger.info("Editing the favorites",html=False,also_console=True)
    logger.info("key url "+OldBookmarkLabel[i],also_console=True)
    # if(d({'textContains':key}))==None:
    #     d({'scrollable':True}).scroll.toEnd()
    d({'textContains':OldBookmarkLabel[i]}).long_click()
    if d({'textContains':"Copy link URL"}).exists & d({'textContains':"Edit"}).exists & d({'textContains':"Remove"}).exists & d({'textContains':"Cancel"}).exists :
        logger.info("coming here, to edit",also_console=True)
        d({'text':'Edit'}).click()
        d({'resourceId':'com.citrix.browser:id/title'}).click()
        if d({"focused":"true"}):
            d({'resourceId':'com.citrix.browser:id/title'}).set_text(NewBookarksLabel[i])
        d({'resourceId':'com.citrix.browser:id/address'}).click()
        if d({"focused":"true"}):
            d({'resourceId':'com.citrix.browser:id/address'}).set_text(NewBookarksURL[i])
        d({'text':'Save'}).click()
     else:
        raise RuntimeError,"Pop up doesn't contain the required fields"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dictionary, try iterating over list.

```
from itertools import cycle

li = [link1,link2]
running = True
licycle = cycle(li)
# fetch the next element
nextelem = licycle.next()
while running:
  thiselem, nextelem = nextelem, licycle.next()
```

You can refer this-

[Getting the next element while cycling through list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167868/getting-next-element-while-cycling-through-a-list)

Comment: I want to use it in key value format, as I am using both key and values. Anyways, thanks for your input.

Comment: In that case, you try by storing the next iterated items and override the key, value if possible.