# Python range with start larger than stop

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I want to extract the `i` indices of a vector uniformly `t` times. For instance, if I have a vector `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, `i = 3` and `t = 5`, my indices in each time must be:

```
t = 1; [1,2,3]

t = 2; [4,5,6]

t = 3; [7,1,2]

t = 4; [3,4,5]

t = 5; [6,7,1]
```

Would it be possible to do it in **Python** with `range()`?

Comment: The itertools module should be useful, an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167868/getting-next-element-while-cycling-through-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Make a `cycle` object from the iterable, and `slice` the object using your window size `i`:

```
from itertools import cycle
from itertools import islice

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
t = 5; i = 3

c =  cycle(l) 
r = [list(islice(c, i)) for _ in range(t)] # range appears here
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 1]]
```

You can apply this for different non-negative values of `i`, and even when `i` is greater than the length of your list:

```
i = 10
r = [list(islice(c, i)) for _ in range(t)]
print(r)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
xc = len(x)
i = 3

for t in range(5):
    y = [x[(i*t + j) % xc] for j in range(i)]
    print(y)
```

This produces:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 1]
```